# arcpy save a shp file to a mxd

Tags: shapefile, arcpy

Using arcpy, how do I save a shapefile to a mapping document (mxd) file?? 
In ArcGis you simply file -> save a copy, but it has shown to be much more complicated in arcpy so far.

```
import os, sys, string, arcpy, arcpy.mapping, glob, arcgisscripting, time
from arcpy import env

workspace = "C:/users/Documents/maps/"
curmap= workspace + "current.shp"
```

I've gone through the ArcGIS Help 10.1 text and they start up once you have an mxd file, and I still need to create the mxd file. This question is the closest thing I have found to a potential answer.. Do I need to change my file from a shp file to a gdb or feature layer before saving to mxd?
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129713/arcpy-saveacopy-method-saving-copy-of-mxd-to-wrong-path

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're wanting to add a shapefile to an new mxd. First you need to create a blank mxd by opening ArcMap and Save As to create a blank mxd. Then make a feature layer of your shapefile and then add it to the mxd.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import mapping

blank_mxd_path = r"C:\blank_mxd.mxd"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(blank_mxd_path)
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

shapefile_path = r"C:\path\to\file.shp"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(shapefile_path, "nameinTOC")
layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("nameinTOC")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, layer, "AUTO_ARRANGE")

mxd.saveACopy(r"C:\location\of\your\new\mapDoc.mxd")

del mxd
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you are going to need to save your shapefile to an .MXD. You set the workspace, but you are essentially saving the shapefile to this path, not the MXD.

What you will need is:

```
import arcpy

workspace = "C:/users/Documents/maps/"
```

If you would like to use your current open MXD, use this code:

```
arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
```

Otherwise, you will need to have a map document name, i.e. the MXD you are trying to save this particular shapefile to. Also, you want to set the current data frame as well.

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(path + r"\YOUR MXD NAME HERE")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
```

Then, take your shapefile (whole path) and:

```
shp_path = r"SHAPEFILE PATH.shp"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(shp_path, "NAME AS SHOWN IN TABLE OF CONTENTS")
lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer("name in the Table of Contents")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, layer, "AUTO_ARRANGE")
```

This will add the layer to the data frame you set.

Finally, you will want to delete the mxd variable you created to free up space:

```
del mxd
```